# Access Worksheet by name including ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

This has been bothering me for a while. I want to access Worksheet by name instead of "how worksheet has been named in Excel". I would like also to include `ThisWorkbook` in the line, to eliminate possibility of having several Workbooks open with Worksheets with the same name. However I am getting an error:

I have named my Worksheet `CalculationItem1`. Why following does not work?

```
Sub TestTest()
    ThisWorkbook.CalculationItem1.Range("A1:A2").Copy
End Sub
```

Following error appears:

[image]

---

Following works but there is a possibility of having same named Worksheet in another opened Workbook? Then errors can appear?

```
Sub TestTest()
    CalculationItem1.Range("A1:A2").Copy
End Sub
```

---

Here is the name:

[image]

Comment: Is CalculationItem1 your spreadsheet name or a variable name that refers to your worksheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the sheet is in the same Workbook as the code ("ThisWorkbook"), you can access the sheet via it's *code name*. That is true even if the Workbook is not active - it's like you have an object-variable with that name. So using `CalculationItem1.Range("A1:A2").Copy` will always refer to the sheet with the code name `CalculationItem1` of `ThisWorkbook`.

If you want to access a worksheet of another workbook via *code name*, you have to iterate the sheets and look for the property `CodeName` (as FaneDuru shows in his answer).

Comment: So it means that in case of using CodeName I basically don't need `ThisWorkbook` as it will always be `ThisWorkbook`? Even if I will open two Excel Workbooks with two same CodeNames, there will be no errors or mismatch between two Workbooks?

Comment: If you use the codename and as long as there is a sheet in the workbook (with that name) where the code resides, it will always refer to the sheet in that workbook (even if the workbook with the code is not active). Even if you have 2 workbooks open, and they both have sheets with the same name, it will still refer to the sheet within the workbook with the code

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that is possible to directly define the sheet using a specific `CodeName`.

But you can avoid confusing about such a sheet and another one of the active workbook, similarly named, using a function like this:

```
Function SetShByCN(strCodeName As String, wb As Workbook) As Worksheet
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    If sh.CodeName = strCodeName Then Set SetShByCN = sh: Exit Function
 Next
End Function
```

It must be adapted to send a warning in case of not existing such a sheet, or to return `Nothing` and this to be checked in the code calling the function. This is only made for testing reason...

It will do the job being called like in the next test code:

```
Sub testSetShByCN()
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Set wks = SetShByCN("CalculationItem1", ThisWorkbook)
  Debug.Print wks.Name
  sh.Range("A1:A2").Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This will help in the future for iterating through the worksheets with CodeNames.

Comment: @hatman: Glad I could help! I used such a way  for my worksheets and I believe it is not possible to return a kind of `VBComponent` `Parent` property, since it does not exist. But I can't swear it is certainly not possible... Should I understand that this code is not the answer you expected?

Comment: This is a little bit beyond what I have asked. I was mainly wondering should I use `ThisWorkbook` in case of CodeName as I was a little bit confused with how detailed you have to specify your range in order to prevent future errors. Anyway your answer is a good addition to my answer. I will refer to it later once I will need to find specific CodeName in some Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

In your first piece of code, you need to tell Excel that you are referring to a worksheet:

```
Sub TestTest()
    ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("CalculationItem1").Range("A1:A2").Copy
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: This is the basic approach. However now if you rename your worksheet to something else, your all VBA codes will give an error. By renaming Worksheet in VBE you can avoid that. So your Worksheets can be renamed to anything you want without affecting your codes. My question is more like how to include ThisWorkbook as well.

Comment: So you want to refer to a Worksheet item without using either its name or position?

Comment: `CalculationItem1.Range("A1:A2").Copy` following works but there is a possibility of having same named Worksheet in another opened Workbook? Then errors can appear?

Comment: I want to use name and include that it is `ThisWorkbook` this will be ultimate solution for pointing at ThisWorkbook and at this Worksheet.