# Excel unique worksheet name

Tags: excel

How can I select worksheet in excel using vba even when sheet name and sheet position changed constantly?

I was using sheet index to avoid vba fail to select worksheet after changing the worksheet name, however, if I change relative position of the ws, its index changes.

I noticed that sheet name in vba project browser, there is a item called (name) which is a fixed sheet number (I guess it was named by the sequence that I created the ws.) Is it possible to select ws based on this fixed name?

Thank you

Comment: "Is it possible to select ws based on this fixed name?" Yes, you are referring to the sheet codename.

Comment: Thank you, it was confusing as I initially thought sheet index should be fixed and same as the codename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Name in VBE to specify your name for Worksheet. This will allow you to rename your Worksheet in Excel according to your needs.

In VBA you can then use something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

MyWorksheetName.Activate

End Sub
```

This is where you edit your Name:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. 1 follow up question, if I have a worksheet named Sheet1 in VBA,  I found that I cannot add workbook.Sheet1 to my code, somehow it doesnt work, if my vba is working on multiple workbooks, with default name like Sheet1, I guess it wont work, any suggestion? I revised all worksheet name to more specific name by adding prefix to it

Comment: @TakChan - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549008/how-can-i-get-worksheet-code-name-to-activate-a-specific-worksheet).

Comment: I have asked the same question some time ago. =)) You can check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031764/access-worksheet-by-name-including-thisworkbook